# PHP Year 2038 Bug - List of Deprecated Functions

Tags: php

I know that the `time();` function will stop working after Year 2038 right?

**Are there any other related functions that might not work ?**

For instance, is `date();` going to work ok ? Is it safe to use it ?

Comment: God I hope PHP wouldn't still exist in 2038. Let alone PHP on a 32bit box.

Comment: I think the problem is for 32bit machines only. Everything will continue to work fine on 64bit

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use the `date()` function but if you use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/DateTime) class, it will work for nearly everything except `DateTime::getTimestamp` because that would return a Unix timestamp, which would of course be the wrong date.

Edit: `getTimestamp` will continue to function correctly on 64-bit machines; the problem lies with 32-bit machines as the number would be too big and would then wrap around to the wrong date.

Comment: what if you call getTimestamp using a 64bit machine ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this will work correctly on 64 bit machines. (But obviously not on 32 bit machines.)